# Cell and Column on XLSX Apache Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I really have some problems with my code. Really appreciate it if any of you would help me. Below is my code and 2 screenshots of what it looks like and how it should looks like when the code is being executed.

```
try {
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ ReportID + ".xlsx");

String excelFileName = "C:\\Test.xlsx";
XSSFWorkbook w = new XSSFWorkbook();
System.out.println("w: " + w);
XSSFSheet s = w.createSheet(ReportID);
System.out.println("s: " + s);

// Report Title
s.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(Title);
System.out.println("Title: " + Title);

// Populate the worksheet
int _col_cnt = HeadersLabel.length;
XSSFRow row = s.createRow(_col_cnt);
System.out.println("HeadersLabel: " + _col_cnt);

for (int c = 0; c < _col_cnt; c++) {
// Construct the header row
String _h = HeadersLabel[c];
System.out.println("_h: " + _h);

if (_h != null) {
    XSSFCell hd = row.createCell(c);
    hd.setCellValue(_h);                    
}       

 int r = 3;     
for (Iterator iter = Cells.iterator();iter.hasNext();) {
                Object[]  _o = (Object[]) iter.next();
                currentRow = s.createRow(r);
            for(int colNum = 0; colNum < _col_cnt; colNum++){
                XSSFCell currentCell =currentRow.createCell(colNum);       

                if (CellDataType[c].equals("STRING")
                        || CellDataType[c].equals("VARCHAR")) {
                    String _l = (String) _o[colNum];
                    if (_l != null) {
                        currentCell.setCellValue(_l);
                        System.out.println("Data: " + _l);
                    }       
                }

    else if (CellDataType[c].equals("DOUBLE")) {
                    Double _D = (Double) _o[c];
                    if (_D != null) {
                        //XSSFCell cell = rowData.createCell(c);
                        cell.setCellValue(_D);
                    }

                } else if (CellDataType[c].equals("INTEGER")) {
                    Integer _I = (Integer) _o[c];
                    if (_I != null) {
                        //XSSFCell cell = rowData.createCell(c);
                        cell.setCellValue(_I);

                    }
                } else if (CellDataType[c].equals("DATE")) {
                    Date _aDate = (Date) _o[c];
                    if (_aDate != null) {
                        //XSSFCell cell = rowData.createCell(c);
                        cell.setCellValue(_aDate);
                    }
                } else if (CellDataType[c].equals("TIMESTAMP")) {
                    Timestamp _aTimestamp = (Timestamp) _o[c];
                    Date _aDate = Timestamp2Date(_aTimestamp);
                    if (_aDate != null) {
                        //XSSFCell cell = rowData.createCell(c);
                        cell.setCellValue(_aDate);

                    }
                }
        r++;
    }

}

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);
//w.write(response.getOutputStream());
w.write(fos);
fos.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
if (out != null) {
    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

context.responseComplete();

}
```

The XLSX excel did not manage to capture some data. The first two column is empty when there is suppose to be data appearing. Only the third column has the data.

What it looks like now: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vfxsootyln6qq5/Capture3.JPG What it suppose to be like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d0yctgk4pywh140/Capture2.JPG

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the data source... However I have tried to solve your problem As far as possible. Please change it wherever you need.

```
 try {
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ ReportID + ".xlsx");
        String excelFileName = "C:\\Test.xlsx";
        XSSFWorkbook w = new XSSFWorkbook();
        System.out.println("w: " + w);
        XSSFSheet s = w.createSheet(ReportID);
        System.out.println("s: " + s);

        // Report Title
        s.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(Title);
        System.out.println("Title: " + Title);

        // Populate the worksheet
        int _col_cnt = HeadersLabel.length;
        XSSFRow row = s.createRow(_col_cnt);
        System.out.println("HeadersLabel: " + _col_cnt);

        //For Headers
        int headerRowNum = 2; //for App, ShortName, LongName
        XSSFRow currentRow = s.createRow(headerRowNum);
        for(int headerCol =0; headerCol <_col_cnt; headerCol++){
            currentRow.createCell(headerCol).setCellValue(HeadersLabel[headerCol]);
        }


        // for Date entry 
        for(int dataRow=3;dataRow < 20;dataRow++){
            currentRow = s.createRow(dataRow);
            for(int colNum=0;colNum<_col_cnt;colNum++){
                XSSFCell currentCell =currentRow.createCell(colNum);
                if (CellDataType[c].equals("STRING") || CellDataType[c].equals("VARCHAR")) {
                    String _l = (String) _o[c];
                    if (_l != null) {
                        currentCell.setCellValue(_l);
                    }

                } else if (CellDataType[c].equals("DOUBLE")) {
                    Double _D = (Double) _o[c];
                    if (_D != null) {
                        currentCell.setCellValue(_D);
                    }

                } else if (CellDataType[c].equals("INTEGER")) {
                    Integer _I = (Integer) _o[c];
                    if (_I != null) {
                        currentCell.setCellValue(_I);

                    }
                } else if (CellDataType[c].equals("DATE")) {
                    Date _aDate = (Date) _o[c];
                    if (_aDate != null) {
                        currentCell.setCellValue(_aDate);
                    }
                } else if (CellDataType[c].equals("TIMESTAMP")) {
                    Timestamp _aTimestamp = (Timestamp) _o[c];
                    Date _aDate = Timestamp2Date(_aTimestamp);
                    if (_aDate != null) {
                        currentCell.setCellValue(_aDate);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there will be error because there isn't any for loop for c under header.
So there will be error at celldatatype ? 
I am not too sure yet because I have not try on it yet.

Comment: what is 'c' used as Index?

Comment: used for column. To allow the header title to start from 0, so the title will start from column A (in excel).

Comment: I tried and sort of manage to solve the c error. But the _o still has error because there isn't object line left.

Comment: I posted another solution at the answer part. But I am not sure if it's right. 
Just that for this new solution, it did manage to print out everything that I want but right after one row of data, it give two empty row.
HERE, how it looks like:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/buchhfke60ifliy/new.JPG

Comment: I understand that I need to remove the iterator loop but there will be error for the String _l because my object is dependent on the iterator loop.