# How to remove iterator loop and allow cellDateType to work in xlsx java?

Tags: java, excel, iterator, apache-poi, xlsx

Hi to all experts out there, 
Currently I have some problem regarding the iterator loop. I need to remove it in order for my data to appear on my xlsx excel sheet but I am not sure how do I go about removing it such that my codes are error free. And I suspect that the error may be on the iterator loop.
For now, this is my codes and an image link of how it looks like now.

[image: How it looks now]

The data in the excel sheet are not suppose to have a space in between but apparently, there is. There isn't any data in the first column because I didn't have any data being keyed in into the website. So it's okay for the first column to be blank.

```
      int r = 3; 
      for (Iterator iter = Cells.iterator();iter.hasNext();) {
           Object[]  _o = (Object[]) iter.next();
           currentRow = s.createRow(r);
      for(int colNum = 0; colNum < _col_cnt; colNum++){
         XSSFCell currentCell =currentRow.createCell(colNum);       

                if (CellDataType[c].equals("STRING")
                        || CellDataType[c].equals("VARCHAR")) {
                    String _l = (String) _o[colNum];
                    if (_l != null) {
                        currentCell.setCellValue(_l);
                        System.out.println("Data: " + _l);
                    }       
                }
```

hardcode (Testing):

```
 int r = 3; 
            for (Iterator iter = Cells.iterator();iter.hasNext();) {
                Object[]  _o = (Object[]) iter.next();
                currentRow = s.createRow(r);
            for(int colNum = 0; colNum < _col_cnt; colNum++){
                XSSFCell currentCell =currentRow.createCell(colNum);       


                currentCell.setCellValue("Hello");
```

[image: hardcode]

Comment: So you are writing something from java into an xslx file and you are getting spaces around the strings ?

Comment: Cool. Can you break your problem into two parts? First can you hard code something in your java code and write that into xlsx. Let us know if that works?

Comment: @Hirak I am actually getting these data from a website. And I have to be able to use java and allow the data from the website to be transferred to the xlsx sheet

Comment: @Hirak 
I have edited and place the hardcode on the "Qns" section. 
I am sorry if it's wrong and the hard code is not what you want to see because I am really weak in coding. This is how it looks like now: https://www.dropbox.com/s/smdpi43d41rrarr/hardcode.JPG

Comment: What is the `Cells` object that you refer to on the second line of code?

Comment: @DavidWallace 
The data from the excel/website

Comment: Dropbox is blocked here. But can you tell us how you figured that your data is containing extra spaces?

Comment: @Hirak 
I've posted the image up there on the question section already. After coding, I am able to "download" the xlsx file from the website. So after downloading and when I opened the file, there is spaces in between my data. 

I guess that the iterator loop might be the caused of it because it's going through the loop and repeating/overwrite my previous data?

Comment: But what class is it?

Comment: @DavidWallace public void? 
public void deliverExcelReport_xlsx(String ReportID, String Title,
   String Criteria, String[] HeadersLabel, String[] CellDataType,
   List Cells) {

Comment: @DavidWallace
Actually here's whole of my code to this question. Maybe you can see a clearly picture here :/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721320/cell-and-column-on-xlsx-apache-java

Comment: Yeah, I can see the problem now that you've shown your whole code.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in the code you've shown here, but it's in the code that you showed in your earlier question.  Two words of advice.

- If you used indentation correctly, and lined up the curly braces where they're supposed to be, you would see the error almost immediately.
- If you stepped through your code with the debugger, and looked at the value of `r`, you would have found the problem immediately.

Your line `r++;` is inside the inner loop.  This means it gets incremented 3 times for each iteration of the outer loop.  You need to move `r++;` down one line, so that it's outside the inner loop, but inside the outer loop.  That way, it will get incremented just once per row, which is what you need.

Comment: Omg it works!
The positioning of the code is really important! I always thought it's the for loop... 
Thank you so much, David!!